# Apache Spark - Saving Models

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am currently working on apache spark and I am trying to run the java code from a web application. When I try to run the code as java application it works fine. But when I try to deploy it as web application, when the program reaches the stage of saving model i.e. `model.save(sparkcontext,modelpath)` I am receiving a `permgen java.lang.OutOfMemory exception`. But when i try to write the model as a object file like:

```
    File modelFile = new File(modelPath);
    if(!modelFile.exists()){

            modelFile.createNewFile();

    }
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(modelFile);
    ObjectOutputStream oout = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
    oout.writeObject(model);
    oout.close();
```

It works fine. How is the `model.save()` implemented in apache spark?

Is there any other way to save the model?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the class of the model?

Comment: I am working on random forest regression model.

Comment: @BalachandarS : Is the model a RDD? are you trying to save the RDD into file?

Comment: Yeah it has RDD and also a hash map!

Comment: @BalachandarS : you need to show the model implementation, the question is not clear.. if you are have some RDD<Model> then you wanted to save it in a file, you can call rdd.saveAsTextFile() method.. which will call the Model class toString() method.

Comment: Try to allocate more memory to your web server using -XX:MaxPermSize... It may be that when calling Save it is loading the dependencies required and they don't fit in memory.

Comment: **Not** as a recommended solution, but as a workaround, perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/41701147/942774 is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a Permgen memory issue.You can try using the below configurations to solve your problem.

If you are using the JVM provided by Oracle you can increase the permgen memory by
using the parameter `-XX:MaxPermSize=256M (or some other amount of space)`. If you are using any other JVM's you can read the documentation and try increasing permgen memory.